# How can I remove from dom fully upon ajax return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I trying to remove completely from DOM LI Elements and it's contents including it's checkbox input but haven't been successful.

I have the following function being called after ajax callback, but it removes the contents not the element it self and childs (readyState == 4):

```
function removepostview(str){

    document.getElementById('post'+str).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Sample LI

```
<li id="post58">Some Text Here<input type="checkbox" id ="postchk58" value="58" onclick="deletepost(this.value);" /></li>
```

Please note that no UL is specified in this scenario intentionally. The LI will be normally onto a UL / OL in all other scenarios with proper markup.

Comment: Thank You all for your quick answers. This community rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible doing this without resulting to a js library:)

```
 var e=   document.getElementById('post'+str);
 e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `remove()` method in jQuery for just such a task:

```
$('#post'+str).remove();
```

Comment: You should use an octothorpe to select the element by its id.

Answer (score 1):

Your tags include jQuery, so why not try this:

```
$('#post' + str).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
function removepostview(str){
    $('#post'+str).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('myUL');
var oldLI = document.getElementById('post'+str);
d.removeChild(oldLI);
```

Comment: In the usage sample no UL was present so it didn't work. 'parentNode' was suggested by @Contra which picked the correct item. Your code also works perfectly when this line is altered to "oldLI.parentNode.removeChild(oldLI);". Thank you so much for your help and answer.

Comment: LI elements are usually inside an UL (or OL).

Answer (score 0):

```
function removepostview(str){
  var postLi = document.getElementById('post'+str);
  document.removeChild(postLi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this returns error: Node was not found"  code: "8